# What kind of heat shield will Federatsiya (Federation) have?

Tags: russia, heat-shield, crew-module

Federatsiya (or Federation) is Russia's next generation crew vehicle, to replace Soyuz.  According to its [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federation_(spacecraft)), it may be reusable:

> Roskosmos reserved the option of making the crew module of the spacecraft reusable, reckoning that a cone-shaped capsule could possibly fly up to 10 missions during a 15-year lifespan.

That raises the question: **What type of thermal protection system will it have?**

[image: Federatsiya]

Previous answers that reference Federatsiya/Federation:

- https://space.stackexchange.com/a/31206/26446
- https://space.stackexchange.com/a/18468/26446

Comment: I have no actual info, but a replaceable ablative shield seems the most likely. Cheap, well understood, proven technology.

Comment: New photo https://habrastorage.org/webt/b8/td/tc/b8tdtcaz_uizfom8lbvjr1pj-ai.jpeg